# Attempting to parse a string using BISON, Flex and LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, bison, lex

I'm playing around with Flex, BISON and LLVM, creating my own programming language to understand how compilers work better. I've got a basic parser working and a syntax going off of this series of blog posts http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/

However, I can't figure out how to extend it to include strings, such as `string myVar = "testing 123"`.

Here's my list of tokens...

```
[ \t\n]                         ;
"extern"                return TOKEN(TEXTERN);
"return"                        return TOKEN(TRETURN);
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*  SAVE_TOKEN; return TIDENTIFIER;
[0-9]+\.[0-9]*              SAVE_TOKEN; return TDOUBLE;
[0-9]+                          SAVE_TOKEN; return TINTEGER;
\"[^\n"]+\"             SAVE_TOKEN; return TSTRING;

"="                               return TOKEN(TEQUAL);
"=="                            return TOKEN(TCEQ);
"!="                            return TOKEN(TCNE);
"<"                             return TOKEN(TCLT);
"<="                            return TOKEN(TCLE);
">"                             return TOKEN(TCGT);
">="                              return TOKEN(TCGE);

"("                             return TOKEN(TLPAREN);
")"                             return TOKEN(TRPAREN);
"{"                                 return TOKEN(TLBRACE);
"}"                             return TOKEN(TRBRACE);
"=>"                    return TOKEN(TCLO);
"co"                    return TOKEN(TCO);
"const"                 return TOKEN(TCONST);
"let"                   return TOKEN(TLET);

"."                                 return TOKEN(TDOT);
","                             return TOKEN(TCOMMA);

"+"                             return TOKEN(TPLUS);
"-"                             return TOKEN(TMINUS);
"*"                             return TOKEN(TMUL);
"/"                             return TOKEN(TDIV);

.                       printf("Unknown token!\n"); yyterminate();
```

Here's my parser...

```
%{
    #include "node.h"
        #include <cstdio>
        #include <cstdlib>
    NBlock *programBlock; /* the top level root node of our final AST */

    extern int yylex();
    void yyerror(const char *s) { std::printf("Error: %s\n", s);std::exit(1); }
%}

/* Represents the many different ways we can access our data */
%union {
    Node *node;
    NBlock *block;
    NExpression *expr;
    NStatement *stmt;
    NIdentifier *ident;
    NVariableDeclaration *var_decl;
    std::vector<NVariableDeclaration*> *varvec;
    std::vector<NExpression*> *exprvec;
    std::string *string;
    int token;
}

/* Define our terminal symbols (tokens). This should
   match our tokens.l lex file. We also define the node type
   they represent.
 */
%token <string> TIDENTIFIER TINTEGER TDOUBLE TSTRING
%token <token> TCEQ TCNE TCLT TCLE TCGT TCGE TEQUAL
%token <token> TLPAREN TRPAREN TLBRACE TRBRACE TCOMMA TDOT TCLO TCO TCONST TLET
%token <token> TPLUS TMINUS TMUL TDIV
%token <token> TRETURN TEXTERN

/* Define the type of node our nonterminal symbols represent.
   The types refer to the %union declaration above. Ex: when
   we call an ident (defined by union type ident) we are really
   calling an (NIdentifier*). It makes the compiler happy.
 */
%type <ident> ident
%type <expr> numeric expr string
%type <varvec> func_decl_args
%type <exprvec> call_args
%type <block> program stmts block
%type <stmt> stmt var_decl func_decl extern_decl const_func_decl let_func_decl
%type <token> comparison

/* Operator precedence for mathematical operators */
%left TPLUS TMINUS
%left TMUL TDIV

%start program

%%

program : stmts { programBlock = $1; }
        ;

stmts : stmt { $$ = new NBlock(); $$->statements.push_back($<stmt>1); }
      | stmts stmt { $1->statements.push_back($<stmt>2); }
      ;

stmt : var_decl | func_decl | extern_decl | const_func_decl | let_func_decl
     | expr { $$ = new NExpressionStatement(*$1); }
     | TRETURN expr { $$ = new NReturnStatement(*$2); }
     ;

block : TLBRACE stmts TRBRACE { $$ = $2; }
      | TLBRACE TRBRACE { $$ = new NBlock(); }
      ;

var_decl : ident ident { $$ = new NVariableDeclaration(*$1, *$2); }
         | ident ident TEQUAL expr { $$ = new NVariableDeclaration(*$1, *$2, $4); }
         ;

extern_decl : TEXTERN ident ident TLPAREN func_decl_args TRPAREN
                { $$ = new NExternDeclaration(*$2, *$3, *$5); delete $5; }
            ;

const_func_decl : TCONST ident ident TEQUAL TLPAREN func_decl_args TRPAREN TCLO block
                { $$ = new NFunctionDeclaration(*$2, *$3, *$6, *$9); delete $6; }
                ;

let_func_decl : TLET ident ident TEQUAL TLPAREN func_decl_args TRPAREN TCLO block
              { $$ = new NFunctionDeclaration(*$2, *$3, *$6, *$9); delete $6; }
              ;

func_decl : ident ident TEQUAL TLPAREN func_decl_args TRPAREN TCLO block
            { $$ = new NFunctionDeclaration(*$1, *$2, *$5, *$8); delete $5; }
          ;

func_decl_args : /*blank*/  { $$ = new VariableList(); }
          | var_decl { $$ = new VariableList(); $$->push_back($<var_decl>1); }
          | func_decl_args TCOMMA var_decl { $1->push_back($<var_decl>3); }
          ;

ident : TIDENTIFIER { $$ = new NIdentifier(*$1); delete $1; }
      ;

string : TSTRING { $$ = new NString($1->c_str()); delete $1; }
      ;


numeric : TINTEGER { $$ = new NInteger(atol($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
        | TDOUBLE { $$ = new NDouble(atof($1->c_str())); delete $1; }
        ;

expr : ident TEQUAL expr { $$ = new NAssignment(*$<ident>1, *$3); }
     | ident TLPAREN call_args TRPAREN { $$ = new NMethodCall(*$1, *$3); delete $3; }
     | ident { $<ident>$ = $1; }
     | numeric
         | expr TMUL expr { $$ = new NBinaryOperator(*$1, $2, *$3); }
         | expr TDIV expr { $$ = new NBinaryOperator(*$1, $2, *$3); }
         | expr TPLUS expr { $$ = new NBinaryOperator(*$1, $2, *$3); }
         | expr TMINUS expr { $$ = new NBinaryOperator(*$1, $2, *$3); }
     | expr comparison expr { $$ = new NBinaryOperator(*$1, $2, *$3); }
     | TLPAREN expr TRPAREN { $$ = $2; }
     ;

call_args : /*blank*/  { $$ = new ExpressionList(); }
          | expr { $$ = new ExpressionList(); $$->push_back($1); }
          | call_args TCOMMA expr  { $1->push_back($3); }
          ;

comparison : TCEQ | TCNE | TCLT | TCLE | TCGT | TCGE;

%%
```

Finally, here's my code generation C++ code for strings...

```
Value* NString::codeGen(CodeGenContext& context)
{
    // Generate the type for the global var
    ArrayType* ArrayTy_0 = ArrayType::get(IntegerType::get(getGlobalContext(), 8), value.size() +1 );

    // create global var which holds the constant string.
    GlobalVariable* gvar_array__str = new GlobalVariable(*context.module,
                                                         /*Type=*/ArrayTy_0,
                                                         /*isConstant=*/true,
                                                         GlobalValue::PrivateLinkage,
                                                         /*Initializer=*/0, // has initializer, specified below
                                                         ".str");
    gvar_array__str->setAlignment(1);
    // create the contents for the string global.
    Constant* const_array_str =  ConstantDataArray::getString(getGlobalContext(), value);
    // Initialize the global with the string
    gvar_array__str->setInitializer(const_array_str);

    // generate access pointer to the string
    std::vector<Constant*> const_ptr_8_indices;
    ConstantInt* const_int = ConstantInt::get(getGlobalContext(), APInt(64, StringRef("0"), 10));
    const_ptr_8_indices.push_back(const_int);
    const_ptr_8_indices.push_back(const_int);
    Constant* const_ptr_8 = ConstantExpr::getGetElementPtr(ArrayTy_0, gvar_array__str, const_ptr_8_indices);
    return const_ptr_8;
}
```

In my own syntax, when I run... `int myInt = 123` that works fine, however, `string myString = "123"` that triggers a syntax error.

Comment: I don't see a using of TSTRING in your grammar. As well as any references to NString.

Comment: If you read [the FLEX manual page](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html) (search for the section about `START CONDITIONS`) they show an example on how to handle C-style double-quoted strings. Of course, using them in the parse might by a good idea too.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you have lot of pointers in your Bison union, including some things that probably should not be pointers like your vectors and the string. Even though you probably have it because unions have problems with object instances, you might still want to consider your design for it, or at least what these pointers are really pointing to and possibly how to free the memory allocated for them to point to.

Comment: @Zefick -  very good spot! I added a string grammar entry and I'm still getting 'syntax error'. I've updated the original example to what I have now

Comment: Doesn't bison give you a warning about the non-terminal `string`?

Comment: @rici - Nope, the parser code compiles okay, it's only when I run my own syntax through the parser that I get a 'syntax error'.

Comment: That's odd, because I don't see anywhere that you actually *use* the non-terminal and bison normally warns about non-terminals which are defined and unused.

Comment: @rici I fixed that issue, now I'm getting: 

`Assertion failed: (isValidElementType(EltTy) && "Invalid type for pointer element!"), function get, file /private/tmp/llvm@3.8-20161231-36794-aou1xo/llvm-3.8.1.src/lib/IR/Type.cpp, line 684.`

When I do `string test = "Test"`